# Do I need to install mysql before using rmysql package?

Tags: mysql, rmysql

Do I need to install the mysql database on my computer before using the RMySQL package?

Comment: You just need the packages that are listen under 'Depends' here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html

Comment: Thank you Luuk. But when I issue the line: con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "test"), an error occurs: Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: As RMySQL is a client, yo still need a MySQL database, but not necessarily "on my computer". You could also connect to a MySQL database which is installed somewhere else.